# a4j:ajax listener: class does not have the property 'doEditAction'

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component, propertynotfoundexception

I've got an *orderingList* with *jsf* and want to do something when I click an item in my list. I build a composite component and tried to use it like this:

**Composite Component**

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="listId" />
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.util.List"/>
    <cc:attribute name="var"/>
    <cc:attribute name="clickListener"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <rich:orderingList id="#{cc.attrs.listId}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <c:set target="#{component}" property="var" value="#{cc.attrs.var}"/>
        <a4j:ajax event="click" listener="#{cc.attrs.clickListener}"/>
    </rich:orderingList>
</cc:implementation>
```

I use this *orderingList* as following:

```
<mycc:orderingList id="myId" clickListener="#{mybean.doEditAction}">
    ...
</mycc:orderingList>
```

In my bean I have the following methods (for testing):

```
public void doEditAction(AjaxBehaviorEvent pEvent) {
    System.out.println("EVENT FIRED WITH AJAX EVENT");
}

public void doEditAction() {
    System.out.println("EVENT FIRED WITHOUT PARAMS");
}

public void doEditAction(ActionEvent pActionEvent) {
    System.out.println("EVENT FIRED WITH ACTION EVENT");
}
```

When I open this view I'm getting an **PropertyNotFoundException**:

> The class 'Mybean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy' does not have the property 'doEditAction'.: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:

Whats wrong with my code? 
I just want to get the selected Item in my bean-method...

Comment: Read the error carefully, it is seen as 'property', so it searches for a cooresponding getter, not an action method. If you implement 'getDoAction()' it will not give the error but not really work good either. I have no time to find a corresponding Q/A in StackOverflow. Using google for https://www.google.com/search?q=pass+actionMethod+composite+component+ajax might give you some results

Comment: Thanks, i used google but nothing is working... i used it without an composite component and it worked but now i've got the problem that i can not use my var as an parameter...